# 13.10/SiS 771/671 Consoles (ctrl-alt-f*) aren't working in fallback mode

Tags: 13.10, console

I'm installing Ubuntu 13.10 in an old computer with a SiS 771/671 video board. It's too old to run Unity, so I had to use fallback mode. The startup and desktop are ok, but when I try to use to the consoles (ctrl-alt-f*) video changes to an unsupported mode and all I get is a rolling garbage screen. The shutdown screen is in the same situation.

Anyone knows how to get the consoles (ctrl-alt-f*) working in fallback mode with this board ?

Thanks